# Export to excel from Gridview Data

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am working in windows form application. I want to export my gridview data to excel with SaveAs(browse) option.

Please suggest.

Comment: Ehr. It's a Windows forms application. Why do you expect a web technology to work in that?

Comment: It means that the current HttpContext is null.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the current `HttpContext` (`HttpContext.Current`) is `null`.

This is because this is a Windows Forms application, not an ASP.NET website. You can't just do that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no HttpContext in windows form application so this is null in your case

Answer (score 3):

HttpContext.Current is not null only for web applications. In windows app it is always null.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext`or `HttpContext.Current` seems to be null.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code for exporting, because you are using a code intended for exporting asp.net gridviews:

```
public void export_datagridview_to_excel(DataGridView dgv, string excel_file)
{
    int cols;
    //open file
    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(excel_file);
    //determine the number of columns and write columns to file
    cols = dgv.Columns.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        wr.Write(dgv.ColumnsIdea.Name.ToString().ToUpper() + "\t");
    }
    wr.WriteLine();
    //write rows to excel file
    for (int i = 0; i < (dgv.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (dgv.RowsIdea.Cells[j].Value != null)
                wr.Write(dgv.RowsIdea.Cells[j].Value + "\t");
            else
            {
                wr.Write("\t");
            }
        }
        wr.WriteLine();
    }
    //close file
    wr.Close();
}
```

Comment: To me this seems to be a completely unrelated answer.

Comment: @UweKeim: No, this is not, because I know that the asker is trying to use a ready code that is used for exporting gridview content to excel. I was able to just answer with 'Dude! you ain't have access to HttpResponse in winform apps, but I tried to help him/her with an actual solution'